# Cucumber + Mongoose is giving me Schema hasn't been registered for model

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, cucumberjs

The error message:

```
MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "User".
Use mongoose.model(name, schema)
at Mongoose.model  (/Users/JimBarrows/Desktop/TaskVelocity/cucubmer/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:349:13)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/JimBarrows/Desktop/TaskVelocity/cucubmer/features/support/hooks.js:3:21)
```

My world.js file:

```
/**stuff**/
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');
require('../../../public_ui/models/Users');
var User = mongoose.model('User');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://192.168.99.100:27017/task_velocity');
```

As I understand it, this should setup mongoose quite nicely.  Then in hooks.js:

```
'use strict';
 var mongoose = require('mongoose');
 var User = mongoose.model('User');
```

I've tried, in the hooks.js file:

```
'use strict';
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('../../../public_ui/models/Users');
var User = mongoose.model('User');
```

but that gives me the same error when I try to get ahold of the model.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you add the contents of '../../../public_ui/models/Users.js' to your question?

Comment: Please also provide your Schema and why haven't you assigned any variable to `require('../../../public_ui/models/Users');`?

Comment: Verify that you actualy define "User" (singular) in yourl model "...public_ui/models/Users" (plural)

Answer (score 2):

Jim Barrows, considering that the error is:

> MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "**User**".

and that your **world.js** has the following lines:

> require('../../../public_ui/models/**User**s');
>
> var User = mongoose.model('**User**');

I believe that is just a typo error and you could fix it easily by doing the following:

```
var User = mongoose.model('Users'); // instead of var User = mongoose.model('User');
```

**which by the way is exactly what *dafyk* commented in your post (not an answer) some days ago...

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but...

check this [link](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html)

You have to make schema and set **mongoose.model('User',schema);**

Can you show me "Users.js" source?;
If you want make module,
like this source

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

    var UserSchema = new Schema({
        username: String,
        passwrod: String
        //Have to Custom
    });

    module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

and use this

```
var Users = require('../../../public_ui/models/Users');
```